# im getting "variable has been referenced before intialization" error at the last line in django framework

Tags: python, django, web-applications

```
def result(request):
    check = None
    try:
        check = user_answers.objects.get(username=request.session["username"])
    except:
        check = None
    if check:
        results,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5 = getPredictions(check)
        username = request.session["username"]
        ans = clusterNum.objects.create(username_id=request.session["username"],clusNo =             results[0],extroversion=a1,neurotic=a2,agreeable=a3,conscientious=a4,openness=a5)
        ans.save()
        
    # results = getPredictions()
    return render(request,'result.html',{'name':username,'a1':a1,'a2':a2,'a3':a3,'a4':a4,'a5':a5})
```

i tried converting them to global but the result is not as expected,it show no values in the webpage

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\Django\predictor\Personality\views.py", line 230, in result
return render(request,'result.html', 
{'name':username,'a1':a1,'a2':a2,'a3':a3,'a4':a4,'a5':a5})

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /personality/result
Exception Value: local variable 'results' referenced before 
assignment
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you expect the caller of: `result(request)` to do if the user is not found? You need to provide something for them. Did you mean to indent the return so that there would be a default return None?

Comment: traceback has been attached

Comment: retun should always return something other than null, my concern is making the variables accesible anywhere within the function

Comment: But what does it mean to return the variables if the user is not found?

Answer (score 1):

In this code, the variables only get values inside the 'if check:' clause. In other words, when this line of code raises an exception:

> check = user_answers.objects.get(username=request.session["username"])

or when the check variable has a negative value (False, 0, None, empty list...), the interpreter doesn't get inside the 'if check:' clause. Therefore your variables (username, a1 ...) don't "exist". Yet they are called on the last line.

Comment: you are right ,but i need the variables to be accessible throughout the function, what can i do?

Comment: You can give them initial values before the 'if' statement.